# How do you save what you've done in a module without keeping the computer on?

Tags: python, savestate, easygui

Am going to design a game about raising dragons but don't know a way of saving my session/exp/stats so it would be ***pointless!*** Can't work out how to use pickle so can somebody give me an answer? 
P.S.Simplify your answers as I am stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link for info on basic I/O in the standard library: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html You will want to store the data from the game in some format (that is up to you) to a file, and then, later, you will read the file, and parse the data, and put it back into memory when the user comes back from a previous session.